# Auto number a column in Excel, and include ranges when specified by another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have two columns in Excel.  I need to auto number the values in Column A, but some of those values will be dependent on Column B.  For the dependent values, I need a solution that will input a range of numbers based on the value in column B.  So, if cell B1 has a 3 in it, then when I auto number column A, I'd need cell A1 to wind up being 1-3.

Here's another example.  If Column B looked like this:

```
Column B
[empty cell]
2
3
[empty cell]
```

Then I'd want the result to look like this after filling in column A:

```
Column A    Column B
1    
2-3         2
4-6         3
7
```

Is there an easy way to do this when writing a formula for Column A?  Or, is there a better way altogether to auto number a column in Excel while optionally including number ranges in some of the cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

In A2 enter:

```
=SUM(B$1:B1)+COUNTBLANK(B$1:B1) & IF(B2<>"","-" & SUM(B$2:B2)+COUNTBLANK(B$2:B2),"")
```

and fill down

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!  I didn't know about the COUNTBLANK function, but that's extremely helpful.